# Woocommerce hook to show product gallery images as full size images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Can someone show how we can use this code with Woocommerce?

I am using this code from
[Woocommerce product gallery images are showing as full size images instead of thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54673066/woocommerce-product-gallery-images-are-showing-as-full-size-images-instead-of-th)
but not working. (maybe, I just don't know how to use it )

```
 add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','wps_add_extra_product_thumbs', 5);
 function wps_add_extra_product_thumbs() {

     if (is_product()) {

         global $product;

         $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

         echo '<div class="product-thumbs">';

         foreach( array_slice( $attachment_ids, 0,3 ) as $attachment_id ) {

               $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' )[0];

               echo '<img class="thumb" src="' . $thumbnail_url . '">';

         }

         echo '</div>';

     }

  }
```

Comment: This hook is used for displaying product content within loops. Its unclear what yo u want to achive. In the example the user ask how to make full sized images in thumbnails. You are asking how to make those images full size? Here is a visual guide to help you - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' )[0];
```

instead of

```
$thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' )[0];
```